# How to use PlaidML with nighly Keras bulds?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, plaidml

Whenever I try to use `from tensorflow import keras` PlaidML refuses to work and `import keras` uses stable build.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras` only uses `tensorflow` as backend, it does not have the multi-backend option. Only the `keras` package has multi-backend support, so if you want to use PlaidML, you can only do it with the `keras` package.